# Does Salesforce have an on-premise solution?

Tags: security, certification

For companies that do not want to have their data in the cloud, does Salesforce offer an on-premise solution? If not, what solutions/certifications do they provide for security conscious or highly regulated industries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first answer: no, there's no on-premise solution.

For the second answer: Their data centers are the Fort Knox (when it had gold) of Information Technology. There's more than I would reasonably want to list here, but you might start here: http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/learn

There's lots of EU, US, and Asia laws that they are compliant with, compliance with various security recommendations, including ISO 27001, PCI-DSS, etc, and many sociological and technological solutions.

I suggest you take time to read everything, or at least whatever is of concern to your security profile. Salesforce.com is certified to do business with the government, health care providers, and financial institutions.